# How to obfuscate an Android library (.jar file) from eclipse

Tags: android

Hi I need to create a create a obfuscated jar. I want to distribute it client so want my code to be obfuscated .

Comment: Does proguard not obfuscate?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531187/android-and-obfuscation

Comment: I know that making changes in proguard-project.txt file and uncommenting  the  proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt line in  project.properties and then creating a signed apk will obfuscate my APk file but how to create a obfuscate jar file

Answer (score 0):

http://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/overview

Try that obfuscator, works really good